# How do I serve html thru svn ? (Can svn act as a web server?)

Tags: html, svn

I have checked in javadocs(html files) into svn. But, when I access the html files thru a browser, it gets interpreted as text. How, do I fix this ?

Comment: If you didnt understand the question, just move on. Don't vote down. If I knew everything there is to know about an issue, I wouldn't be here. Looks like someone else was able to interpret my question.

Comment: Agreed. Unexplained down-votes are only half as helpful as they could be.

Comment: Sorry for the late comment! I think your question could be more clear. That's what my downvote was for. Meanwhile I tried to answer it as best as I could with the poor description. ;-)

Comment: Agreed, it could have been described better. But, maybe you can be less generous with your down votes. And, your answer is what I wanted. So, the phrasing couldnt have bee that bad.

Comment: @smartnut007: It's better now. :-)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

SVN is not a webserver. I guess you are talking about Subversion's Apache module!? If you want to view .html files as HTML then you should set `svn:mime-type=text/html`:

```
svn propset svn:mime-type text/html *.html
```

See [Properties](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.props.html) in the SVN Book.

> Also, if the `svn:mime-type` property is
>   set, then the Subversion Apache module
>   will use its value to populate the
>   `Content-type:` HTTP header when
>   responding to GET requests. This gives
>   a crucial clue about how to display a
>   file when perusing your repository
>   with a web browser.

Maybe you can configure your subversion client or server with the following lines in the [config file](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.confarea.html#svn.advanced.confarea.opts.config):

```
[miscellany]
### Automatic properties are defined in the section 'auto-props'.
enable-auto-props = yes

### Section for configuring automatic properties.
[auto-props]
*.html = svn:mime-type=text/html
```

This will automatically set the properties for new files.

Comment: yes, was referring to the web server component of the svn server. ah yes, mime types. After recursively setting the mime type, it worked.

Comment: the given solution is not worked me, check this one for server side configuration: http://serverfault.com/questions/451500/is-it-possible-for-the-subversion-apache-module-to-serve-html-files-with-an-html/454517#454517

Comment: worth mentionning that `text/css` and `text/javascript` can be used for css and js files, allowing the use of the webview for a more than just basic html viewer

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to change the behaviour in general, you may be able to modify the mime type with your SVN client. E.g. for Tortoise SVN do the following:

- go into the Repo Browser
- right click onto the desired file and select "Show properties"
- if there already is a "svn:mime-type" property hit "Edit ..."
- if not, hit "New ..." and add the property "mime-type"
- in the mime-type edit dialog you can choose between text, binary and custom. When choosing custom, you can set what ever you want. E.g. text/html, or video/mp4.
- hit ok until all dialogs are closed.
- you are done.

This way you can define the behaviour per file which is sometimes very usefull.