# How to Force a Web Browser to Interpret A File As HTML

Tags: html, browser

I am trying to upload a .htm file onto a remote SVN repository to be viewed by other members of my team in their web browsers.

When queried, the repository only displays my .htm file as plain text, although when I run the file from my local hard drive, it is interpreted by my browser as html. The repository is on an https server.

I have prefaced my html code with various tags that are supposed to alert the browser that the file is html, such as

```
<Content-Type="text/html">
```

and

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

and even this one that I really don't understand but tried anyway:

```
<contentType="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
```

But nothing is working... Does anyone know some sweet, fool-proof way to trick a browser into interpreting a file as html?

Comment: possible duplicate of [serving html thru svn server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4100121/serving-html-thru-svn-server)

Comment: This could be a security feature. You might not be able to change it.

Comment: You need to make sure you are saving the file as a text/html MIME filetype with UTF-8 Encoding. This is doable in any advanced text editor like EditPadPro or such

Comment: None of those 'in file' things will override the [`Content-Type` HTTP header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields), if the browser has been told it's a text file it's not going to parse any of those HTML tags.

Comment: Ah, I think you guys are right about this being a property of the server. I guess I'll just have to deal with it some other way. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is related to the settings of the SVN repository. There is nothing you can put in the body of the .htm file that will cause the browser to parse the file as html. It is a server security feature.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and resolved it:

Add an SVN property 'mime-type=text/html' to your local file (using tortoisesvn for me) and then commit it.

It will solve the problem and the Mime-type is saved even if you commit again your file (if you don't change the file name of course).

for my CSS file, I did the same using 'mime-type=text/css'

But the best way should be associating files extension and SVN mime-text property on the server side.